# Why does the htaccess rewritecond using %{query_string} only work when the URL contains index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess redirect like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tabid=53
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com/foobar? [R=301,L]
```

So, when I visit `example.com/?tabid=53` nothing happens, `example.com/index.php?tabid=53` gets redirected to `/foobar`. When I add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
```

nothing will change, from my understanding this should say "does not matter if there is index.php or not in the uri". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the only rewrite rule you have set? Other rules may be conflicting with it. Anyway you should try to log what the mod_rewrite is doing - see the rewriteloglevel directive docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel for Apache 2.2, it's changed in version 2.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tabid=53
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/foobar? [R=301,L]
```

I assume problem with your single dot is, that the dot matches any single character, but there is none to be matched in your `example.com/?tabid=53`. If you use `example.com/i?tabid=53`, then it works.

Comment: Provide some description

Comment: actually it was because of the `RewriteRule . `, `RewriteRule ^ ` works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this weird behaviour by matching `.*` instead of `.`.
You can also match `root level` or `index.php`.

Both solutions are working as expected.

**Solution 1**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tabid=53 [NC]
RewriteRule .* /foobar? [R=301,L]
```

**Solution 2**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tabid=53 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(|index\.php)$ /foobar? [R=301,L]
```

**Conclusion**

The problem with your rule

```
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com/foobar? [R=301,L]
```

is because `.` means `one character` and never matches since it's empty (no file, directly query string on root level).

That's why `.*` matches (means `0 or more characters`) or `RewriteRule ^(|index\.php)$` (which means `match root level -empty- or index.php`)